# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (255, '')

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

string =  pytesseract.image_to_string(res,lang ='eng',config = config)

I am getting an error as:
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (255, '')

i am cropping the images and performing some image processing tasks. After that I want to do ocr, on running the ocr i am getting the error.

string =  pytesseract.image_to_string(res,lang ='eng',config = config)

expected the ocr result. but tesseract is throwing an error and stops executing

Comment: provide all input information, not only last command...

Comment: i have found solution to the error..padding the images along the border resolves the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times the text may lie on the border of of the images. So padding the images along side the border resolves the issue